# Request to third party API in an Ember route's model hook

Tags: ajax, ember.js

I have a need to request some data from a third party API endpoint in an Ember app (Using Ember 1.7)

I'm not sure the best way to handle the response, should I:

- Use `$.ajax` in my model hook, return the raw data and not worry
  about Ember models?
- Use `$.ajax` in my model hook, use `store.createRecord` to map the
  returned data into models and use `store.all` to return this data to
  my component.
- Use an adapter and use `store.findAll` to get the data (could be
  tricky as the returned data won't match my models).

I'm not quite sure of the pros and con's of getting data in this way, any input would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with the second option but instead of creating the record, it's better for you to push payload into the store. It's better because after pushing into the store, you won't get your model `dirty`, it would have `root.loaded.saved` state. More about pushing into the store in this [guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/)

Hope I helped you.

Comment: I'm needing to use a very old version of Ember unfortunately and the API suggests that payload isn't an available push option, only a model.
https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/
Any thoughts? At the moment I seem to have the correct number of records in my output, but none of the fields have any data in them. 
I can post some code and screenshots if it helps.